# Gnuplot: sphere with parameters from file

Tags: file, geometry, gnuplot

I`m trying to draw a sphere with X, Y, Z, R given in file with the help of gnuplot.

sphere1.dat:

```
# X     Y      Z       R
219.3  342.5  3153.2  213.08
```

In most examples spheres are drawn this way:

```
set parametric
set angle degree
set urange [0:360]
set vrange [-90:90]
set isosample 72,36
splot cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v)
```

Is there any way to combine u,v values with ones from file?
Something like that:

```
set angle degree
set urange [0:360]
set vrange [-90:90]
set isosample 72,36
splot 'sphere1.dat' using ($4*cos(u)*cos(v)+$1):($4*sin(u)*cos(v)+$2):($4*sin(v)+$3) title "Sphere1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get x,y,z,r from your datafile using tail and awk.

```
tail -1 data
```

prints last line of data

```
awk '{print $i}'
```

returns i'th space-separated part of line

```
x = "`tail -1 sphere1.dat| awk '{print $1}'`"
y = "`tail -1 sphere1.dat| awk '{print $2}'`"
z = "`tail -1 sphere1.dat| awk '{print $3}'`"
r = "`tail -1 sphere1.dat| awk '{print $4}'`"

set parametric
set angle degree
set urange [0:360]
set vrange [-90:90]
set isosample 30,30
splot r*cos(u)*cos(v)+x,r*sin(u)*cos(v)+y,r*sin(v)+z
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to run this on windows? "warning: system evaluation not supported by MS-Windows 32 bit"

Comment: I'm not good at windows shells, so I can't tell you windows equivalent. 
Fortunately there is MinGW. It provides most of nix commands http://www.mingw.org